# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Rails while raising HTTP REQUEST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ssl

I am getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError while making one http_request. Please find the code mentioned below.

```
 require 'net/http'
 uri = URI.parse("http://webaddress.com")
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 http.use_ssl = true
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
 request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/v1.1/auth")
 request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
 request.body = {"auth_token"=>"abcd"  ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
 response = http.request(request)
```

It's throwing following error :

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

Please  let me know why this error is coming? and what could be the reason for this error.

Comment: `http.use_ssl = true` it should be `false` as you call `http`

Comment: @RajarshiDas it's working. but its throwing another error undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0xb4335ec8>

Comment: should I create a post ?

Comment: `request.body = {"auth_token"=>"abcd"  ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}` for this

Comment: ya sure. please do that

Comment: what its throwing bytesize error?

Comment: `request.set_form_data({'name'=>'Sur Max', 'email'=>'some@email.com'})`

Comment: your hash is not correct

Comment: i changed as you said. now its throwing #<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>